# iMacros - XPATH - Compare text XPATH with text reference

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, imacros

Using iMacros, I want to read the text of an XPATH. If the text read matches the expected, continue to run the task. If the read text of the XPATH does not match the expected text, reread it (looped, until it matches the expected one).

I have managed to read the XPATH text, extract the text and save it in a txt. But it's not what I'm looking for.
The idea is the following:
Example:
Textreference = "New Message"
Textoxpath = "" // Initialization to 0, for example

If (textoreferencia == textoxpath)
Execute code and exit
Else
Read xpath again

I've thought about creating a variable with the reference text.
Create another variable with the XPATH text, and compare these two variables.
But I do not know how to write that code on xpath.

EDIT WITH CODE:
I have:

`URL GOTO=https://www.google.es
SET !VAR1 1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG XPATH="//div[@id='tabmbTab1']" EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\F17MC\Desktop FILE=extraction.txt`

Comment: post code please!  hard to visualize what you're doing.

Comment: edit with code! @James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying this way:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.google.es
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET textoreferencia "The expected text"

' let's wait until the expected text appears (e.g. one day) '
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 86400
TAG XPATH="//div[@id='tabmbTab1'][text()='{{textoreferencia}}']" EXTRACT=TXT
' restoring the default value '
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6

' ...
```

Comment: Oh!! Yeah, this works the way I want it, but I would want to use logic, so if the text matches the expected text, do a .imm sequence. And if it does not match what was expected, check it again. Do you know how I could do it? I think it is necessary to use JavaScript for it.

Comment: If you use 'iMacros for Firefox', it's possible to apply the [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface). Otherwise, some workarounds depending on your code features.